# Suggest web reporting tool for Spring, JSP

Tags: java, spring, report, reporting

I am currently working on the reporting module of a Spring/JSP/Hibernate based web application and want to know which reporting tool would be best for my application.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Java, you have mostly the 3 following options: Jasper Reports, Pentaho or BIRT, all of them are good, and widely used and tested, so i recomend you to give them the spin and see which one is better for your needs.